# when i put file with punctuation marks in a textview, other symbols are shown

Tags: java, android, text

when i put txt file in texte view  in android studio  punctuation marks Their place shows symbols

```
  String data ="";
     String data_coding ="";
    StringBuffer stringBuffer  = new StringBuffer(  );
    InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource( R.raw.t1 );
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) );

    if (inputStream != null){
        try {
            while ((data = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null){

                stringBuffer.append( data + System.getProperty( "line.separator" )  );


            }
            textView.setText( stringBuffer );


            inputStream.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not clear what you asking about

Comment: ponctuation marks  don't show correcte